# Alert on error react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to display an error message in the component when a 401 is returned from the API. I am trying to use a state that is not bound to anything and am using ES6. I am getting

`Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

This is the login function:

```
login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({loginFailed: true});
    });
}
```

Comment: if you fat arrow the function what happens?

Comment: `function (err) => { ` same thing :(

Comment: You should drop function and just have it as `(err) => {...}`

Comment: you could also set a local variable to `this` before `AuthService` is invoked and reference that same variable in the `.catch` callback. But `=>` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Camron_Godbout see my answer below, but the fat arrow is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the promise resolution, you're losing the scope of this from the outer object and are in the promise's context.

Since you're using ES6, you can use the fat arrow to bind the outer this to the inside of the function.

```
login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({loginFailed: true});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree DVG's answer is best provided you are using ES6.

However, you could also do this.

```
login(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var self = this;

  AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    self.setState({loginFailed: true});
  });
}
```